# solve error: variable is void: projectile-mode-map

Tags: projectile

I'm trying to bind projectile-find-file to a keyboard shorcut and running in to this error.

Apparently projectile is installed, because M-x listing shows at least a dozen projectile prefixed commands.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projectile might not be loaded. (require 'projectile) should work fine.

Some projectile functions, listed by M-x,  are just prepared to be autoloaded.

EDIT: Thanks, @Basil

The answer above is not wrong. But in your init.el, writing `(require 'projectile)` is not recommended, because projectile can be loaded on your first time to use one of the projectile functions prepared to be autoloaded. Writing `require` in init.el lead longer startup time of Emacs. So replace the `BODY...` with provided `define-key`s on below code:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'projectile BODY...)
```

`BODY` in `with-eval-after-load` is evaluated after loading of projectile. So this code makes sure that `BODY` is evaluated after defining `projectile-mode-map`.

On the other hand, if you just want to try the key binds only on the current sesstion, requiring projectile and evaluating them are easy, i think.

Technical Words: "Require" has almost same meanings as "load." It means reading el(c) file and making the feature available.

Comment: It's often better to write `(with-eval-after-load 'projectile (define-key projectile-mode-map ...))` than to eagerly load `(require 'projectile)` in an init file, as the latter slows down Emacs startup. See [`(info "(elisp) Hooks for Loading")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html).

Comment: @Basil You are right. Almost all the setting of `PACKAGE` is surrounded by `(with-eval-after-load 'PACKAGE ...)`. In this case, `M-x projectile-mode`(more recommended) or `(require 'projectile)` should be run to use projectile.

Comment: Sure, but the question is not about how to load `projectile`, it's about how to safely bind keys in its keymaps before it is loaded. Which is why I'm suggesting mentioning `with-eval-after-load` (or even `use-package`).

Comment: @Basil I've thought with-eval-after-load is better and what s/he needs, too. I just forgot the word, "besides." Sorry for my mistake. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: No mistake, thanks!

Comment: legit! answer thanks